# Kernel Panic Ubuntu Xenial on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to build a vagrant machine with Ubuntu 16.04 using VirtualBox and getting a kernel error. It crashes the whole vagrant machine and happens very randomly. I say random beacuse, the vagrant build goes smoothly and I can work on the local server for a while until it crashes. If you have come accross something similiar, please help me solve the issue. Here are the ubuntu log entries:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS ubuntu-xenial ttyS0

ubuntu-xenial login: [ 3147.436387] Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffffc033ec6f
[ 3147.436387] 
[ 3147.477651] CPU: 1 PID: 1695 Comm: python Not tainted 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu
[ 3147.576987] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[ 3147.587476]  0000000000000086 000000002e86a334 ffff8800421dfa18 ffffffff813f9513
[ 3147.811873]  ffffffff81cba598 ffff8800421dfab0 ffff8800421dfaa0 ffffffff8118d607
[ 3148.077952]  ffff880000000010 ffff8800421dfab0 ffff8800421dfa48 000000002e86a334
[ 3148.206471] Call Trace:
[ 3148.211965]  [<ffffffff813f9513>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[ 3148.399282]  [<ffffffff8118d607>] panic+0xd3/0x215
[ 3148.556695]  [<ffffffffc033ec6f>] ? VbglR0SfCreate+0xaf/0xb0 [vboxsf]
[ 3148.567643]  [<ffffffff81081119>] __stack_chk_fail+0x19/0x20
[ 3148.645791]  [<ffffffffc033ec6f>] VbglR0SfCreate+0xaf/0xb0 [vboxsf]
[ 3148.766156]  [<ffffffffc033cbac>] ? sf_inode_revalidate+0x8c/0xe0 [vboxsf]
[ 3148.918265]  [<ffffffff810cb001>] ? __raw_callee_save___pv_queued_spin_unlock+0x11/0x20
[ 3148.958786]  [<ffffffff81228da6>] ? __d_lookup+0x116/0x150
[ 3149.036532]  [<ffffffff812266f4>] ? dput+0x34/0x220
[ 3149.166361]  [<ffffffffc033cc13>] ? sf_dentry_revalidate+0x13/0x30 [vboxsf]
[ 3149.386320]  [<ffffffff8121a3af>] ? lookup_fast+0x24f/0x330
[ 3149.597049]  [<ffffffff812199c8>] ? __inode_permission+0x48/0xc0
[ 3149.742830]  [<ffffffff8121ba79>] ? walk_component+0x49/0x300
[ 3149.978073]  [<ffffffff8121b46b>] ? path_init+0x1eb/0x3c0
[ 3150.034405]  [<ffffffff8121d4fd>] ? path_lookupat+0x5d/0x110
[ 3150.171957]  [<ffffffff8121f141>] ? filename_lookup+0xb1/0x180
[ 3150.211906]  [<ffffffff811ed747>] ? kmem_cache_alloc+0x187/0x1f0
[ 3150.416598]  [<ffffffff8121ed46>] ? getname_flags+0x56/0x1f0
[ 3150.491161]  [<ffffffff8121f2e6>] ? user_path_at_empty+0x36/0x40
[ 3150.696048]  [<ffffffff81214076>] ? vfs_fstatat+0x66/0xc0
[ 3150.915222]  [<ffffffff812145ce>] ? SYSC_newstat+0x2e/0x60
[ 3151.021599]  [<ffffffff8121475e>] ? SyS_newstat+0xe/0x10
[ 3151.050559]  [<ffffffff81840b72>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[ 3151.121914] Kernel Offset: disabled
[ 3151.167006] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffffc033ec6f
[ 3151.167006]
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I was having the same issue. I was able to work around it by using NFS for the synced folders.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Kernel Panic in VirtualBox with this:

Put **2 Processors**

[image]